# How can I combine variables in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a Stata dataset containing variables: `A1`, `B1`, `A2`, `B2`, `A3`, `B3`,..., `A15`, `B15`. All variables with `A` are gender and those with `B` are the corresponding ages.

How can I combine all variables into just two variables, `A` and `B`? So A would be `A1+A2+A3`, ... ,`A15` and similarly for `B`?

Comment: Good questions here show precise data examples and some attempt at code. This makes little sense without an example. What does "combine" mean? Alternatively, in what sense can you add (which is what + means) 15 gender variables or 15 age variables?. At a wild guess you have data on up to 15 members of a family and wish to tabulate ages and genders. If so, you need to `reshape long`.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer seems to be

```
generate A = A1+A2+A3 ...
generate B = B1+B2+B3 ...
```

or less painfully,

```
egen A = rowtotal(A*)
egen B = rowtotal(B*)
```

assuming you have no other variables whose names begin with A or B.

Comment: I don't think I'm right; I think I don't understand what the problem is. To a mathematician, a group of variables connected by `+` represents addition, but I don't think that's what Terry intended. Nick's comment below the original post is probably correct, but Terry should read the guidance at the link I gave and translate his question into something less ambiguous.